# Keras Sequential freezes after compiling, doesn't start fitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras, image-classification

Good Morning, Afternoon or Evening,

I am currently trying to build a simple image classification network for identifying brain tumors. In the process, I ran into the problem of my Keras Sequential model not starting to fit but stopping after compiling. I tried various approches with changing the size of my dataset, training on validation data or reducing the dimension of the input. Furthermore, I am quiete new to machine learning and don't have a lot of knowledge based around Tensorflow, so I am running out of ideas...

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    from DataFetcher import DataFetcher
    fetcher_train =  DataFetcher(data_folder="dataset/set_train",
    file_path_labels="dataset/img_labels.csv")
    fetcher_test = DataFetcher(data_folder="dataset/set_test",
    file_path_labels="dataset/img_labels.csv")
    train_images, train_labels = fetcher_train.get_data(), fetcher_train.simplified
    test_images, test_labels = fetcher_test.get_data(), fetcher_test.simplified

    print("\nShape of input is (240, 240)")

    #(train_images1, train_labels1), (test_images, test_labels) =   
    tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
    model = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation=tf.nn.relu,
    input_shape=(240, 240, 1)),
                tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3)),
                tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
            ]
        )
    print("\nStructured neural network")
    print(model.summary())
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"])
    print("\nCompiled successfully")
    model.fit(x=train_images, y=train_labels, epochs=5, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels),
    validation_steps=1)
```

This is my code for the main class, the DataFetcher basically takes in a path and converts all of the pictures in that directory into an array of the shape 240, 240, 1. The images dont have color, so only using grey-values instead of RGB triples seemed like a good option to me. The simplified attribute refers to the array of simplified labels, read from the csv that came with the dataset. As mentioned above, the whole thing freezes after compiling, I tried it multiple times. As I have somewhat decent specs, I dont think the issue is the complexity of the task and any associated performance problems either. When interrupting the process, I get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "TumorClassification\image_recognizer_v1.py", line 28, in <module>     model.fit(x=train_images, y=train_labels, epochs=5, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), validation_steps=1)   File "TumorClassification\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler     return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "TumorClassification\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1745, in fit     data_handler = data_adapter.get_data_handler(   File "TumorClassification\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1688, in get_data_handler     return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)   File "TumorClassification\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1291, in __init__     adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)   File "TumorClassification\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1102, in select_data_adapter     adapter_cls = [cls for cls in ALL_ADAPTER_CLS if cls.can_handle(x, y)]   File "TumorClassification\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1102, in <listcomp>     adapter_cls = [cls for cls in ALL_ADAPTER_CLS if cls.can_handle(x, y)]   File "TumorClassification\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\data_adapter.py", line 465, in can_handle     ) and not CompositeTensorDataAdapter.can_handle(x, y):   File "TumorClassification\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\data_adapter.py", line 614, in can_handle     return any(_is_composite(v) for v in flat_inputs) and all(   File "TumorClassification\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\data_adapter.py", line 614, in <genexpr>     return any(_is_composite(v) for v in flat_inputs) and all(   File "TumorClassification\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\data_adapter.py", line 607, in _is_composite     return _is_scipy_sparse(v)   File "TumorClassification\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1972, in _is_scipy_sparse     from scipy.sparse import issparse   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 982, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 925, in _find_spec   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1423, in find_spec   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1395, in _get_spec   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1522, in find_spec   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 142, in _path_stat KeyboardInterrupt`

And I already tried updating tf, that was not the problem...

Thank you in advance :)

Edit: For anyone wondering, I fixed it by now. The Problem was too much RAM-Usage because I tried to load all of the pictures rgb-values into one big chonker of an array. Tensorflow provides libraries to handle datasets, I used some of their methods and it works just fine. See this for further help: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images.
Have a nice day :)